# Ipad Mirroring - How to mirror a different view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mirroring

I don't know if "mirroring" is the correct term for this, but I have an Ipad app that takes pictures and keeps them in core data. I've googled around but I can't find code for what I need.

What I want is for the TV to show an image different the iPad. For example, if I don't take any pictures, the TV shows saved images on the screen. When I take a new picture that stops and it shows the new picture.

Comment: The SO community responds most warmly to questioners who provide evidence of serious attempts (however flawed) to solve their own problems.  This 'question' is approximately 'pleez write my kode'.  I suggest OP edits question and shows code.

Comment: "I can't find code for what I need." I think this might be your first problem, has it occurred to you that you might just be required to write code of your own? Shock! Horror!

Comment: My friends.. I don't ask for this. Only what I want is some article or the name for this because I don't know how search for this..

Comment: @LucasMacambas I think you misunderstand what SO is.  SO is a technical Q/A site, not a reference site.  If you had asked _how_ to mirror rather than asking for the code to do so you probably would have gotten a better response.  On the other hand, members can be quite rude at times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find what I wanted in the reference guide.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011045-CH6-DontLinkElementID_3